# Change sprite text dynamic in three.js

Tags: three.js

I use `sprite` create sprite in three.js.
   And it works. But i want to change the canvas texture dynamic.
Maybe i can use `fillText` to change the text.But it works nor very well.
I just want it looks like electronic watch.

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
drawBg(ctx, bg);
drawText(ctx, data);

let texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
let material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture});
let spriteOject = new THREE.Sprite(material);
spriteOject.scale.set(scale * w / h, scale)
spriteOject.position.set(positions[0], positions[1], positions[2]);
```

[image]